# How to automatically keeping specific files in sync between git branches?

Tags: git

Is there a way for git to automatically manage sharing/syncing specific files between branches?
eg. If I have branches: branch1 and master, and I change/commit file1 on branch1, it automatically updates/commits file1 with the same content on master (and vice versa).
In essence, I want a certain set of files to always be in synch in both branches.

I've looked at git submodules, but the files that I want to keep in sync are in various locations (it's the majority of files in the project).
I'm fairly new to git and I haven't been able to completely grasp what git subtree can do. Does git subtree allow what I need? (If so I can spend the time to learn it)

The other option I can think of is to to create a script that uses git-cherry-pick or checkout --patch to keep the files in sync. If I were to go this route, is cherry pick or patch a better option?

Comment: Please explain a bit more why you need these files to be the same on all branches? It feels like they are configuration and probably shouldn't be versioned at all (or in a different system).

Comment: They are code files, a bunch of them are algorithms that get changed/tweaked often. More than anything it's for convenince. There's a set of files that I more or less know before hand that if I change them in one branch, I want them changed in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not work on a per file basis. It works with patches on the complete repository.

You could commit changes in this file as a patch with only that file and cherrypick it in the other branch and vice versa. This could be done as a script. Or more complicated as a post commit hook.

But the first time the changes touch functionality in another file or if you commit more than that one file in such a sync patch you will have a mess.

Keep the sync manually will give you more comfort and savety but some dicipline is needed.

Comment: I tried the command "git checkout --patch branch file" which asked for confirmation before patching any files that could have been commited in the other branch, so that method atleast gives some form of safety. (From what I could gather with cherry pick, you could accidentally overwrite commited changes in the other branch if it was automatic)

Comment: Ah I just thought up making a folder with a repository only for that file and including ist as a git submodule.  Then it will be perfect! (If you use goggle repo in your project it will be even easier)